# TracePrint does not work as in my book

Tags: recursion, debugging

*I am using Mathematica 11.3*

Here is an my execution of code from book "Essentials of Programming in Mathematica" (Fibonacci numbers):

```
F[1]=1;
F[2]=1;
F[n_]:=F[n-2]+F[n-1]
Table[F[i],{i,1,26}]
```

> {1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946,17711,28657,46368,75025,121393}

```
TracePrint[F[4],F[_Integer]F[_]+F[_]]
```

> 3

But instead, the book has:

[image]

**Question:**

Why my I am not getting that step by step execution like in the book when executing `TracePrint` part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably a typo in the book. The pattern `F[_Integer] F[_] + F[_]` does not occur in during the evaluation of `F[4]`.

The code should look like this (notice the `|`):

```
TracePrint[F[4], F[_Integer] | F[_] + F[_]]
```